# Scene Kit View not showing in window

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

I am building a simulation app as a side project for a school paper I'm writing and I started building it as an iPad app initially, and only later realized I needed it on OSX.

I need some way for the user to input values and then I need a Scene Kit View to display my animation.

The problem I am encountering (I didn't have this when programming iOS) is that when I am adding a Scene Kit View in the storyboard (as a child of the main View in the only ViewController) it doesn't load. Everything is building just fine, but I get this Error message printed out right away: `Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (SCNView)`

Note that I am using the Cocoa Application Template

I hope the above is understandable and would be grateful for any help

Comment: Have you added the SceneKit framework to your project?

Comment: No I hadn't! Now it's working just fine.